# Shortcut criteria check with adding decimal as binary

Tags: excel, vba, math

good day,

I've made a program that has several prerequisites before proceeding and have written a scoring system to tally if all criteria are met without needing several if statements.

In addition i continue to write if statements if criteria are not met to alert the issue but this too is getting crazy with if a or b or c or d . . . statements is there a quicker mathematical way to summaries this? In some cases i have 6 or 7 prerequisites, isnt there a way i can count remainder or something of decimal to binary?

here is a dummy example of what i mean

```
dim points as integer
points = 0

if len(range("A1") ) = 6 then points = points + 1             'example checks length
if Cdbl(range("B1") ) >= Cdbl(Date) then points = points + 2  'example checks if date is in future
if not isempty(range("C1")) then points = points + 4          'example checks field is not blank

if points = 7 then
    [do some code]
    msgbox "criteria met"

else

    ' this is what I want summarized with 1 nice mathematical equation

    if points = 1 or points = 3 or points = 5 or points = 7 then
        msgbox "problem is A1"
    end if

    if points = 2 or points = 3 or points = 6 or points = 7 then
        msgbox  "problem is B1"
    end if

    if points = 4 or points = 5 or points = 6 or points = 7 then
        msgbox "problem is C1"
    end if

end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You to just need to use `And`. `points And 1` will return `1` (which will be equivalent to `true` if used that way) if `points` is odd.

`points And 6` will return 6 if the the number in binary ends in 110 or 111.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/logical-and-bitwise-operators

Comment: WOW! thank you for the reference too. I was so lost i knew i could do a modulus calculation but couldn't figure out how to convert. Thank you!! this works great!

Comment: Note that the link is for VB.Net, not VBA, which would perhaps be [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/and-operator).